# What does "ceremonial" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

What does "ceremonial" mean in this context?

```
Thus, it was for freedom (legitimate moral and ceremonial freedom) that Christ set us free.
```

Definitions of "ceremonial":

```
1. relating to or used for formal events of a religious or public nature.
2. (of a position or role) involving only nominal authority or power.
```

From the book "Old Covenant, New Covenant: The Case Against Legalism" By Jesse Acuff

https://books.google.com/books?id=2zuHs1gkyEYC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22ceremonial+freedom%22&source=bl&ots=_BBCyDPygC&sig=9KmObBczx874bENcuUFD-ntPDoA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NkfpVMTQD4HtggSqsYKwCQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22ceremonial%20freedom%22&f=false

Comment: I think you might have to ask the author.  But if I had to guess I'd say he's talking about the "ceremonial" aspects of Judaism -- observing "kosher", etc.

Answer (score 4):

> Thus, it was for freedom (legitimate moral and *ceremonial* freedom)
>   that Christ set us free.

It seems the author quoted was paraphrasing [Galatians 5:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%205&version=NIV) of the New Testament:

> It is for freedom that Christ has set us free. Stand firm, then, and
>   do not let yourselves to be burdened again by a yoke of slavery.

In the larger [context](https://books.google.com/books?id=2zuHs1gkyEYC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22ceremonial%20freedom%22&source=bl&ots=_BBCyDPygC&sig=9KmObBczx874bENcuUFD-ntPDoA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NkfpVMTQD4HtggSqsYKwCQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22ceremonial%20freedom%22&f=false), the author refined his meaning with a specific reference:

> *the moral and ceremonial liabilities of the Law of Moses*.

He also referred to [Acts 15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2015%3A1-10&version=NIV), which discusses an ancient theological dispute about circumcision, the fundamental *ceremony* of Judaism:

> Certain people came down from Judea to Antioch and were teaching the
>   believers: “Unless you are ***circumcised***, according to the custom taught
>   by Moses, you cannot be saved.” [extensive discussion omitted]... Now
>   then, why do you try to test God by putting on the necks of Gentiles a
>   yoke that neither we nor our ancestors have been able to bear?
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

This discussion seems to be consistent with the larger [context of Galatians 5:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%205&version=NIV)

> Mark my words! I, Paul, tell you that if you let yourselves be
>   ***circumcised***, Christ will be of no value to you at all.
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

The nature of this *ceremonial freedom* is a question of theology rather than language, but it seems quite clear that the author of *[Old Covenant, New Covenant](https://books.google.com/books?id=2zuHs1gkyEYC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22ceremonial%20freedom%22&source=bl&ots=_BBCyDPygC&sig=9KmObBczx874bENcuUFD-ntPDoA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NkfpVMTQD4HtggSqsYKwCQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22ceremonial%20freedom%22&f=false)* refers to a New Testament notion of freedom from the *ceremonial* requirement of *circumcision*, which is at the center of Old Testament Judaism.

**Conclusion:**

The author's definition appears to be:

> 1. relating to or used for formal events of a religious or public nature.